# package org.apache.apex.malhar.lib does not exist

Tags: maven, apache-apex

I am trying to execute an apex application consisting of an operator which uses the malhar library for generating random strings. Even though I have included the malhar-library dependency in my pom.xml file I am getting the following error on the mvn clean package -DSkipTests command

**package org.apache.apex.malhar.lib does not exist**

Answer (score 0):

The build error may be caused by a reference to a class that does not exist in the malhar-library version that you are using. To generate a working Maven project, use the following:

```
mvn archetype:generate \
 -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.apex \
 -DarchetypeArtifactId=apex-app-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=RELEASE \
 -DgroupId=com.example -Dpackage=com.example.myapp -DartifactId=myapp \
 -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

For more information, please see: https://github.com/apache/apex-core/blob/master/docs/application_packages.md#using-command-line